# Change view of form on click of button or checkbox

Tags: codenameone, lwuit-form

I have to make a form codename-one in which i have a check box. if check box is checked then bellow it i want to display 2 combo box and if check box is unchecked then i want to display 2 text field.

How can i do it.

I have tried setVisible(true/false) but in it space consumed by label or text field is never covered up.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove/add the components and then invoke either `revalidate()` or `animateLayout(int)` to refresh the UI.